# Small system of filtering users by their roles on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement a function in my controller to filter users of the application by their roles

My controller ProfileController.php has the following function:

```
public function membrevis() {

    $filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : null;

    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_role', 'user.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'users_roles.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('users.valid','=',0)
        ->select('users.*','roles.description');

    if ($filter != null) {
        $users->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
              ->orWhere('roles.description','like','%'.$filter.'%')
    }

    $users->get(); 
    return view('member2',['users'=> $users]);
}
```

My view membre2.blade.php has the following HTML code:

```
<form action="/membre2" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="filter" >
    <button type="submit">filter</button>
</form>
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a common error which means that PHP syntax parser expects a token other than the symbol that the error statement states. In this case, you are getting an error because `;` is missing and the PHP parser encountered `}` instead of `;`

Comment: highly recommend using a linter such as phpcs https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` in the `if` statement

```
public function membrevis() {

$filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : null;


$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('user_role', 'user.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
    ->join('roles', 'users_roles.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
    ->where('users.valid','=',0)
    ->select('users.*','roles.description');


   if($filter != null) {
   $users->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
        ->orWhere('roles.description','like','%'.$filter.'%');
   }
     $users->get(); 
           return view('member2',['users'=> $users]);

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `;` after `->orWhere('roles.description','like','%'.$filter.'%')`

**Code with Updated Indent**

```
public function membrevis()
{

    $filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : null;


    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_role', 'user.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'users_roles.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('users.valid','=',0)
        ->select('users.*','roles.description');


    if($filter != null)
    {
        $users->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
            ->orWhere('roles.description','like','%'.$filter.'%');
    }

    $users->get();

    return view('member2',['users'=> $users]);

}
```

Indent make your code more readable. There are different styles of indention. You can understand them better via [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
    public function membrevis() {

    $filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : null;


    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_role', 'user.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'users_roles.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('users.valid','=',0)
        ->when($filter, function ($query) use ($filter) {
            return $query->where('users.name','like','%' . $filter . '%')
                   ->orWhere('roles.description','like','%' . $filter . '%');
                })
        ->select('users.*','roles.description')
        ->get();


   return view('member2',['users'=> $users]);
 }
```

The instructions in the closure given to when() will only be applied if the first argument is evaluated to true, that way you'll be able to write complex conditional instructions without having to break the query chain.

You should provide more information about your erorr if it will not help.